# How do I install the pg_cron extension in Postgres 13 hosted in my Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, installation, pg-cron

I see a few guides for installing the pg_cron extension in windows, but its very confusing. Is there any guide that can help?
A simple create extension in the database doesnt work. I get the below error :

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/share/extension/pg_cron.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the extension first.

Since you are using Windows, things will get complicated. You need a C compiler and build instructions from source. There are no such build instructions available, but somebody [has managed to do it](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/issues/22) before and [suggested modifications](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/pull/70) that were never merged.

Based on this and my personal experience with pg_cron bugs, I have the feeling that Microsoft doesn't care for this project very much, and that you will have a hard time getting it to run on Windows.

Alternatively, you could try your luck with [pg_timetable](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_timetable), but you'd have to [build that from source](https://pg-timetable.readthedocs.io/en/v4_dev/installation.html#build-from-sources) too.

You might end up using [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/pgagent_install.html), for which pre-built Windows binaries exist.